# How can I change individually the fill of a legend in scatter plot to match the label colors?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I change the filling of each key in the legend to match the labels?

If I do it in geom_label_repel using show.legend = TRUE it doesn't look very good and it puts a letter "a" in place of dots.

[image]

Yellow is for injured players, blue for owned players, green for free players and red for hobbits players.

Here's the code used for the plot:

```
ggplot(fim, aes(Price, Average, 
                      label = Player, 
                      colour = color, 
                      fill = color,
                      #alpha = ih, 
                      group = Position
              )) +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "lightblue", show.legend = FALSE) +
    geom_point(aes(fill = factor(color))) + # 
    geom_label_repel(size = 3.25,
                     family = "Bahnschrift",
                     #fontface = 'bold',
                     label.size = NA,
                     segment.alpha = 0.5,
                     alpha = 0.9,
                     show.legend = FALSE,
                     #label.padding = unit(.22, 'lines'),
                     #hjust = 0,
                     #vjust = 0,
                     #label.r = 0,
                     box.padding = unit(0.20, "lines"),
                     point.padding = unit(0.20, "lines"),
                     #force = 4
                     ) +
    #nudge_y = 0.005,
    #nudge_x = 0) +
    scale_x_continuous(labels=function(y) format(y, big.mark = ".", scientific = FALSE)) +
    ggtitle("Price and Average Points in LaLiga Fantasy",
            paste("Top", nrow(fim), pos, "by market value with at least", minapps, "appearances, excluding Messi & Benzema")) +
    labs(y="Average Points (Sofascore Rating System)",
         x = "Price (Market Value in Euros)",
         caption = "Sources: Biwenger, Jornada Perfecta plot by Weldata") +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("Hobbits" = WT,
                                  "Free" = WT,
                                  "Injured" = BK,
                                  "Owned" = WT)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("Hobbits" = cl,
                                 "Free" = MF,
                                 "Injured" = GK,
                                 "Owned" = DF)) +
    scale_alpha(0.1) +
    dark_theme_gray() +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(family = "Bahnschrift", 
                                    face = "bold", 
                                    size = 18, 
                                    colour = YL),
          plot.background = element_rect(fill = BK),
          panel.background = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "grey30", size = 0.2),
          panel.grid.minor = element_line(color = "grey30", size = 0.2),
          legend.title = element_blank(),
          #legend.background = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks = element_line(colour = "grey30"),
          axis.title = element_text(family = "Bahnschrift", size = 14, colour = WT),
          axis.text = element_text(size = 12, colour = "grey80", face = 'bold'),
          legend.position = c(0.9, 0.2), #legend.position = "none",
          plot.tag = element_text(),
          plot.caption = element_text(color = YL, face = "italic")
          )
```

Comment: You can add a reproductible example: `library(ggrepel)
set.seed(42)

dat <- subset(mtcars, wt > 2.75 & wt < 3.45)
dat$car <- rownames(dat)

p <- ggplot(dat, aes(wt, mpg, label = car)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=car),shape=3)+ 
  geom_label_repel(aes( fill=car)) +

  labs(title = "geom_text_repel()")
p`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `show.legend=F` in `geom_label_repel`

```
library(ggrepel)
set.seed(42)

dat <- subset(mtcars, wt > 2.75 & wt < 3.45)
dat$car <- rownames(dat)
# your problem:
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(wt, mpg, label = car)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=car))+ 
  geom_label_repel(aes( fill=car)) +

  labs(title = "geom_text_repel()")
p
#Answer:
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(wt, mpg, label = car)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=car))+ 
  geom_label_repel(aes( fill=car), show.legend  = F) +

  labs(title = "geom_text_repel()")
p
```